# AngularJS two-way data binding using crockford's pattern - getter/setter

Tags: angularjs

This code works. I am able to display from the model attribute and bind the new value to another attribute of the model. So I think when I submit the data-binding ensures that the specific attribute is updated with the new value.

Isn't there a way to call a setter through AngularJS' data-binding facility ? Now I am updating the attribute directly.

```
<div ng-controller="myAppController">

{{serviceLimit}}

{{serviceLimits.upperlimit}}

{{serviceLimits.getUpperLimit()}}

<input ng-model="serviceLimits.upperlimit">

</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
</button>
```

---

```
  angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']) .config(function($routeProvider) {   

$routeProvider.when('/', {

    templateUrl: 'homeView.html',

    controller: 'myAppController'    
});
})
.controller('myAppController', function($scope) { 


       var serviceLimits = function(serviceSpec){        

              var thatserviceLimit = {};  

              thatserviceLimit.upperlimit = serviceSpec.upperlimit;

              thatserviceLimit.getUpperLimit = function(){
                    return serviceSpec.upperlimit;
              };

              thatserviceLimit.getNewUpperLimit = function(){
                    return thatserviceLimit.upperlimit;
              };

              thatserviceLimit.setUpperLimit = function(limit){
                    console.log(limit);
                    serviceSpec.upperlimit = limit;
              };

              thatserviceLimit.getLowerLimit = function(){
                    return serviceSpec.lowerlimit;
              };

         return thatserviceLimit;
         };

       $scope.serviceLimits = serviceLimits({ 'upperlimit' : 10, 'lowerlimit' : 5 });

       logserviceLimits = serviceLimits({ 'upperlimit' : 10, 'lowerlimit' : 5 });
       console.log(logserviceLimits.getUpperLimit());
       $scope.serviceLimit = 10;
});
```

Comment: I don't call the setters. The two-way databinding works by updating the attributes directly which serves my purpose.

Comment: Because of angularjs [not support IE8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), so I think the native setter is [not a bad idea](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Setter_in_property_initializer)